# Replace Ugly URLs To Pretty And SEO-Friendly

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a .htaccess Rewrite URL solution to convert my web application's ugly URL to Pretty one.Previously I have converted an URL `localhost/example/user.php?u=username` to `localhost/example/username` with the following .htaccess code

`RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1`

now I want to convert the following URL:

`localhost/example/messages.php?u=username` ----> `localhost/example/messages`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep these 2 rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /$1/user.php?u=$2 [L,QSA]
```